# Cypress cy.request returns 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, cypress

I am using Cypress with react and node express server. I am trying to build a test that starts by calling cy.request with post method in order to initialize the state of the app for this particular test, but the response is always 404 as the following

Error:

> CypressError: cy.request() failed on:
>
> mysite.net
>
> The response we received from your web server was:
>
> 404: Not Found
>
> This was considered a failure because the status code was not '2xx' or '3xx'.
>
> If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: 'failOnStatusCode: false'

The request does work in prod/dev (status 200) but in cypress it always returns 404 as mentioned. I also checked the data structure of the request and it seems ok.

I am using the same route for all, the only difference is the method I use:

- dev/prod: standard fetch API call seats under an apiHandler function.
  Cypress: cy.request() method

My code:

```
cy.request({
       method: 'POST',
        url: `auth/login/example-url`,
       failOnStatusCode: false,
       form: true,
       body: {
         arrival: '2021-12-01T17:23',
         departure: '2021-12-01T15:23',
         destination: 'New York',
         origin: 'Washington DC',
       },
     })
```

Thanks ahead for your help:)

Comment: I do not know if this is a result from copy-pasting your code in here, but the quote marks for the url are the wrong ones

Comment: 404 usually suggests the resource doesn't exist. Are you absolutely sure the url it forms in the request with your base url is correct? Check the console in the cypress runner closely after clicking on the request to see exactly what is getting sent.
Can you hit the request successfully with a curl or postman and its just cypress that has an issue? Perhaps there is a required header your are missing (although that doesn't usually result in 404)

Answer (score 0):

- when Browser: send request header and response status code OK
- Using cy.visit(): response status code Not Found

So the problem is the Request Headers, you better check it, and set Headers in cy.visit() to look like Browser Headers. you'll receive the status code OK.